# Tomcat 7.0.25 SessionIdGenerator exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm deploying a spring-boot application with tomcat 7.0.70 and works fine. My problem is that I need it running with tomcat 7.0.25, and when I change the dependency I can't even run the application, the exceptions are:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.SessionIdGenerator
```

I have try all, I surfed nearly all Google and StackOverflow but I can't find a way to include this in my application.

The problem is that working with 7.0.25 is a must, and I guess that if with the embed 7.0.25 doesn't work, in production I will have a problem.

Any tip on how to solve that error would be VERY appreciated.

Lot of thanks!

Comment: can you please show your dependencies?

Comment: remove from pom.xml any explicit <tomcat.version>8.0.9</tomcat.version> or try newer version of spring boot release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Spring Boot` depends on the class that is mentioned in the exception (`org.apache.catalina.SessionIdGenerator`).

According to the [sources](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_58/java/org/apache/catalina/) of `Apache Tomcat` this class is available from 7.0.58 version, so you can't use older version.

You did not provide information which version of `Spring Boot` you are using, but you can try using older version.