# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, deployment, tomcat7

Getting the below error while trying to deploy war server .

Server tomcat version:7.0.57
server java version : 1.7

war created using gradle tools(bootrepackage) in intellij.

Everything works find in intellij during development.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
   dependencies {
       classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.10.RELEASE")
    }
}
group 'batch'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}

war {
    baseName = 'Batch'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'src.main.java.com.Application'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'src.main.java.com.Application'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.1.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.24'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.1.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '7.0.82'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.1.10.RELEASE'
    //compile group: 'net.sourceforge.tess4j', name: 'tess4j', version: '4.0.2'
    //compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
}
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring Boot versions... You are mixing 1.1.10, 1.4.0 and 1.5.6 next to that you are overriding the spring-data-jpa managed version (already including in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` so you don't need to add it again).

Comment: @M.Deinum changed everything to 1.1.10. But now getting the error while gradle build task.  Error : Could not set unknown property 'addResources' for task ':bootRun' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask.  Had updated the Question description with new build.gradle.

Comment: Why use an ancient Spring Boot version... You where mixing 3 versions , you should only have a version on the plugin the rest of the versions will be automatically managed for you. Switch to the newest Spring Boot version if you can or at least 1.5.x version.

Comment: @M.Deinum   i need to compile with tomcat version:7.0.57 and java 1.7. spring-   boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.1.10.RELEASE' supports tomcat 7.0.57. Not sure what will happen in deployment if i compile with higher version of tomcat.

Comment: If you need that specific version then why are you even including `7.0.82` of jasper? Also why would you need that dependency? It should not be a `compile` dependency but rather a `providedCompile` dependency. Also for compilation it doesn't use anything from tomcat so it doesn't compile anything with it.

Comment: @M.Deinum removing tomcat-embed-jasper results in error : This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: Next to that you are trying to use features `addResources` which are part of a newer Spring Boot version. So that won't work.

Comment: Where did I say you need to remove it. You need a different version AND it should be differently scoped.

Comment: Finally I suggest to use the latest spring boot version in the 1.x range as that should be able to let you use tomcat 7 (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-7).

Answer (score 0):

In your initial question you mixed at least 3 different versions of Spring Boot. 1.1.10, 1.4.0 and 1.5.6. Never mix jars of different versions of a framework (regardless of the framework) as that will lead to interesting results.

Next you are trying to outsmart the Spring Boot plugin by managing dependencies yourself. Let Spring Boot (and the plugin) what they can do for you.

Judging from the `tomcat-jasper` dependency you are trying to use JSP with Spring Boot (although not recommended).

First lets fix the dependency management and used Spring Boot version.

**NOTE:** I used the most recent Spring Boot 1.x version feel free to use a bit older version.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
   dependencies {
       classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.13.RELEASE")
    }
}

group 'batch'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

Next lets fix the tomcat version you want to use (see [how to use tomcat7](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-7)).

```
ext['tomcat.version']='7.0.57'
```

Now cleanup your dependencies so you let spring boot manage the dependencies. As you want to build a WAR archive your `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, as well as the other tomcat dependencies, should be a `providedRuntime` scoped dependency (see. [Packaging war file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging)).

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'

    providedRuntime group:'org.apache.tomcat', name:'tomcat-juli', version:property('tomcat.version')
    providedRuntime group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: property('tomcat.version')
}
```

You should also be able to delete the `jar` task as those are controlled (and disabled) by Spring Boot. You might want to use the `springBoot` section to configure the `main` class.

All this should lead to more or less the following `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
   dependencies {
       classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.13.RELEASE")
    }
}
group 'batch'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

ext['tomcat.version']='7.0.57'

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = com.Application
}

war {
    baseName = 'Batch'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'

    providedRuntime group:'org.apache.tomcat', name:'tomcat-juli', version:property('tomcat.version')
    providedRuntime group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: property('tomcat.version')
}
```

Which should give you a war that is both executable and deployable. The tomcat jars are not on the classpath anymore when deploying to the tomcat server you want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried with the build.gradle you mentioned above. now getting new errors while gradle refresh task. Error : Could not get unknown property 'tomcat' for root project 'batch' of type org.gradle.api.Project. It is showing in the line ext[tomcat.version]='7.0.57'

Comment: Oops, there should be quotes around that.

Comment: build.gradle refreshed successfully. now while trying to start the application getting Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.7.0_80]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [na:1.7.0_80]
 at

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Comment: starting the application how?

Comment: using intellij to start. select application, click the start button. not yet created war.

Comment: That is an IntelliJ issue not including runtime/providedruntime dependencies.

Comment: Earlier i might be doing wrong, mixing versions including unwanted dependencies but was able to start the application and was working with it. The only problem faced was not able to deploy. But now not even able to start. :(

Comment: Your deployment failed because of the wrong dependencies. You can perfectly start your application but you have to tell IntelliJ to add the runtime/provided dependencies. Just build a jar and launch it from the command line or use `./gradlew bootRun` to launch the application.

Comment: After bootrun Error :Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.com.Application
 The error is very clear but cant find the fix anywhere.

Comment: ‘src.main.java’ isn’t part of your package. This is also not in my anwser, I deliberatly removed that already.

Comment: changed to "com.Application" . Now new Error : Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator
I could see this question is asked already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041162/tomcat-7-0-25-sessionidgenerator-exception?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. There also no solution.

Comment: There is a dependency that requires that class. Only solution is to upgrade to a newee Tomcat. As also stated in that other thread.